# how to print value in text box using two drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my app have two dropdown and one text box. Second drop down dependent on first drop down value. and I want text box value depend upon second drop down selected value.

> form

```
<tr>
<td><label>BANK</label></td>
<td>
<select class="form-control" name="bankid" id="vbankid">
<option value="0"></option>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT bankid,bankname FROM bankinfo");
while ($rowc = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value=" . $rowc[0] . ">" . $rowc[1];
}
?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>ACCOUNT</label></td>
<td>
<select class="form-control" name="acno" id="saccountid">
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>NAME</label></td>
<td><input class="form-control" name="txtname" id="sname"></td>
</tr>
```

> javascript

```
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="../../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
<script src="../../bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script> 
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true
    });


  $("#vbankid").change(function() {

    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="../../images/loading.gif" alt="loading Topics" /></div>');

    $.get("loadaccount.php?vbankid=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("#saccountid").html(data);
        $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });


 });

  $("#saccountid").change(function() {
    var bankid = $("#vbankid").val();

    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="../../images/loading.gif" alt="loading Topics" /></div>');

    $.get("loadname.php?vbankid=" + bankid + "&vaccountid=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("#sname").html(data);
        $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });


 });


});
</script>
```

> loadname.php

```
<?php

$accountid = $_GET['vaccountid'];

$bankid = $_GET['vbankid'];

$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name FROM accountinfo WHERE accountid='$accountid' and bankid='$bankid'");

while($roww=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

 echo $roww[0];

}

?>
```

I searched some question but nothing is work.I don't understand where is the problem.second drop down value load perfectly but text box not working.please help me

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is the ajax request to `loadname.php` being made? If so, are the parameters sent correct? If so, what is the response? If the request is not made, is the `$("#saccountid").change` handler called at all? Simply saying that something is "not working" doesn't give us a lot to go off of.  Tell us what _is_ happening.  Also, please start using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) ASAP.  Where is `$conn` defined?

Comment: change function called correctly but no data retrieve from loadname.php...I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: You only answered one of my questions.  Please check your browser's developer tools to in check the Network request and update with the answers to my other questions.

Comment: 1st drop down work perfectly.using 1st drop down i get 2nd drop down value but text box data not retrieve. and $conn is db connection

Comment: Well, I tried.  I'm out.

Comment: ok...Thanks for response

Comment: i show that vaccountid not pass to loadname.php

Comment: `"&vaccountid" + $(this).val()`  You have a typo.  You are missing the `=`.

Comment: yes....right...It work...but how i print that value in text box?i am successful to print in drop down.please tell me how i print that to my textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the typo of missing the `=` in `"&vaccountid" + $(this).val()` , you are also using the wrong jQuery method for setting the value of a text input field.  Instead of using `.html()`, you need to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

Replace `$("#sname").html(data);` with `$("#sname").val(data);`

As mentioned in my first comment, you really, *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for your queries.

Comment: thank you..Its work fine..I have one more question.. can I retrieve multiple variable from same php to different text box different value?

Comment: Please do some research and make an attempt to solve this on your own.  If you still have problems, post a new question specific to this issue, and be sure to include what you have already tried and what the result was.